# How to toggle css class on a table head which also has an existing click binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am attempting to `toggle css class` on a `table head`. However, the table header already has a `click binding`: I referenced the [docs here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

I need to have a class on the table head `(thead)` by default and then add/remove (toggle) the class when the head is clicked. The goal is to use the class to add visual descriptions to the table head which are sortable:

Here is the code below doing the sorting: `NOTE:` This code and idea was copied from [Ryan Rahlf blog](http://ryanrahlf.com/). [Article here](http://ryanrahlf.com/sorting-tables-by-column-header-with-knockout-js-part-2/):

I am thinking the css binding can be called from the sort function so that it is applied or removed from column head as they are clicked:

```
    self.sort = function(header, event){

        // This is the existing click binding (sort)
        // Place css logic in here so that individual thead class is toggled when clicked.

        if(self.activeSort === header) {

            header.asc = !header.asc;

        } else {
            self.activeSort = header;
        }

        var prop = self.activeSort.sortPropertyName;
        var ascSort = function(a,b){ return a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : 0; };
        var descSort = function(a,b){ return a[prop] > b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : 0; };
        var sortFunc = self.activeSort.asc ? ascSort : descSort;
        self.Artist.sort(sortFunc);
    };
```

[Example on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23oj337w/):

Comment: Can the click even of the head not do the toggle as well?

Comment: Not from what I have tried, I need to bind the css to the head but adding the css bind as explained in the Knockout docs does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many approach to do this, but to not change many things what you do here, see the snippet one of the approach:

```js
function viewModel() {

        var self = this;
        
        self.orderedBy = ko.observableArray([]);
        
        self.Artist = ko.observableArray([
            {
                'LastName': 'Simon',
                'FirstName': 'Paul'
            }
            ,
            {
                'LastName': 'McCartney',
                'FirstName': 'Paul'
            },
            {
                'LastName': 'McKnight',
                'FirstName': 'Brian'
            },
            {
                'LastName': 'Morrison',
                'FirstName': 'Marc'
            }]);

        self.headers = [
            {title: 'First Name', sortPropertyName: 'FirstName', asc: true},
            {title: 'Last Name', sortPropertyName:  'LastName', asc:true}
        ];

        self.sort = function(header, event){          
          
          self.activeSort = header;  
          
          if(self.orderedBy.indexOf(header.title)>=0)
            self.orderedBy.remove(header.title);          
          else
            self.orderedBy.push(header.title);
          
          self.activeSort.asc = !self.activeSort.asc;
          var prop = self.activeSort.sortPropertyName;
          var ascSort = function(a,b){ return a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] > b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : 0; };
          var descSort = function(a,b){ return a[prop] > b[prop] ? -1 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? 1 : a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : 0; };
          var sortFunc = self.activeSort.asc ? ascSort : descSort;
          self.Artist.sort(sortFunc);
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
```

```css
.ordered{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: headers">
            <th data-bind="click: sort, text: title, css:{ordered: orderedBy.indexOf(title)>=0}"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Artist">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Hope be useful.

Comment: Hello Joel, thank you!: Using your approach, how would I leave the style on both but only remove when the same head is clicked again? For example: Click on `FirstName` and it stays highlighted, click on `LastName` and it also stays highlighted, then if you click first name again, it removes the class. Basically, clicking on different head does not toggle the style, only if you click on the same head.

Comment: Please set a helpful vote, so i will edit my answer  to help you with this. Basically i just will change the ````orderedBy```` property to an ````observableArray```` and verify if the title is in.

Comment: @Asynchronous So the answer was edited, if that is it set as correct please :)

Comment: Just an FYI: After marking as answer, I realized that the sort only works the first time the column is clicked. If I click the column the first time, it sorts, if I click again the css is remove but the sort does not work. The problem is with this line: `self.activeSort = null`. The the sort should go back to the way it ways.

Comment: I know, but the snnipet is just to show you the way. So this dont justify the undo of helpful vote.

Comment: I really do appreciate your effort: However, the vote was given based on the quality of solution. Your solution is a great idea, but I had to use JQuery to toggle the class and did not use knockout CSS binding.

Comment: @Asynchronous, Please see again XD, now it works like your fidlle